# "Page down" stops working after editing

Tags: bug

OS: Windows 10

Browser: Firefox v. 68.4.1esr (32-bit)

Problem: After editing a post, the "Page Down" key becomes unresponsive. After pressing the "Esc" key, the use of the "Page Down" key produces a drop-down menu in the upper left corner containing the selection from the "Edit Summary" line from the recent edit.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open a question
2. Select "edit" on a post
3. Make an edit
4. Fill out edit summary
5. Click "Save Edits"
6. Press the "Page Down" key (not sure if this is necessary)
7. Press the "Esc" key
8. Press the "Page Down" key

Workaround: Changing tabs restores the expected behavior of the "Page Down" key.

[image]

Comment: I did see this on StackOverflow. But then it suddenly stopped, I assumed the problem was fixed. Maybe it's fixed only on SO or something? I think it's probably worth reposting this on [meta.se] - seems like it's a problem that would affect more sites.

Comment: @VLAZ I'll give it a day or two, i suppose, then join the main meta and post it there.